# Does the order of instructions in a CMakeLists.txt file matter?

Tags: cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file which contains a number of commands. (For lack of a better description of what each line in the file is.)

Examples:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
```

Does the order of these things matter, and if so to what extent?

Another way to phrase this question is by asking how does CMake work? Does it read each line of the file, acting like a state machine, and then "execute" the instructions once the file has been read?

Not neccessarily that important to know but interesting none the less.

From what I have seen the documentation tends to focus on how to get something working, and doesn't contain a lot of detail about what is happening or how it works.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't obvious at first glance, but CMake is actually *two* languages with different semantics.

First, there's the one you work with directly, the imperative command language. **Naturally, since it is an imperative language, the order of operations matters in general.** Obviously setting two variables to constant values can be reordered, like in every other imperative language, but if one depends on the other, it's no good.

```
# order doesn't matter here, only incidentally:
set(foo 1)
set(bar 2)

# now the order clearly matters
set(foo 1)
set(bar "baz ${foo}")
```

Now, this is just about the **configure** step because what's really happening here is that you are *meta-programming* the input to the **generate** step. Recall that the generator's purpose is to translate this declarative language into Makefiles, Ninja build files, Visual Studio project files, etc. etc.

This input is in a second language that boils down to "final variable environment, targets, properties, and generator expressions". This language is **declarative**. Generator expressions compute strings based on the environment, and other target properties and those values can propagate through `INTERFACE` properties along the link chains. The order of evaluation is determined by dependencies, and doesn't update any shared state, so you can define targets and set their properties in any order you want.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If two have dependance, then you should give them the right order.

Comment: Such as a compilation order dependency or something else?

Comment: Yes, for example: `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(firstlib)  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(secondlib)`, if firstlib relies on secondlib, you should put the second before the first.

Comment: Makes sense - so this presumably affects the order in which cmake tries to execute the actual compile commands?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant - no. The order of target creation does not affect the order of command execution. Only dependency order matters. It's just that you can't call certain functions on targets in the scripting language until they've been created. Targets are like global hash table variables (unless they're `IMPORTED`).

Answer (score 1):

When **configure** the project, CMake processes `CMakeLists.txt` **line by line**, immediately evaluating variable's dereference, immediately calling functions and macros, etc. So yes, in `CMakeLists.txt` instruction order **matters**.

E.g. in the code

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
```

would the config or module script (which is used by [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)) for SDL dereference `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable, then it would see the value `17`.

Note, that instruction order in `CMakeLists.txt` has nothing common with the order of running commands on **build** stage.

E.g. with code

```
add_executable(exe1 main1.c)
add_executable(exe2 main2.c)
```

it is unspecified in which order the executables `exe1` and `exe2` will be compiled and linked.

---

Also, when parse `CMakeLists.txt`, CMake could defer *some actions* till the end of the script.

E.g the command [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) interprets the first argument immediately, but other non-keyword arguments are interpreted at the end of the script. That way, the order

```
add_library(foo foo.c)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar)
add_library(bar bar.c)
```

is correct, and CMake links `foo` target with the `bar` target, even the latter is not existed on `target_link_libraries` call.

But

```
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar)
add_library(foo foo.c)
add_library(bar bar.c)
```

is wrong: when process `target_link_libraries` call, CMake won't find `foo` target and will emit an error.